# Programming cortex m0+ soic for coustom pcb

Tags: microcontroller, pcb, programming, cortex

I need a little help. I have designed a small HAVC system, controlled with different sensors which  each is connected to cortex m0+ mcu-s. I have tested my program on development board. Now I have to put every thing together.
My problem is that I don't have any idea how to load program on four [Atmel SAM D10C](http://si.farnell.com/atmel/atsamd10c13a-ssut/mcu-32bit-cortex-m0-48mhz-soic/dp/2475672) cortex m0+ mcu-s?
I have search on google for a while and didn't get any answer, so please help me ;(.

Comment: How are you programming the development board? USB, or with a Programmer?

Comment: USB, I use this one http://www.ebay.com/itm/STM32F030F4P6-ARM-CORTEX-M0-Core-Minimum-System-Dev-Board-for-Arduino-/271994391959?hash=item3f54210d97:g:DKcAAOSwiLdWAhsJ

Comment: @amicum - "How are you programming the development board?" -> "USB". Hmm, you cannot *directly* upload a program to your STM32F030F4P6 via USB. Therefore I *guess* you have a PC USB-to-UART adapter, which you have attached to the TxD / RxD pins shown on that development board - is that correct?

Comment: How to program the device is documented by the chip vendor.  One of the things you use the dev board is not only to write the program but to learn to download it.  In some cases the dev board can be used as a programmer board for your own pcb.  Not always though.

Comment: While not quite a duplicate, it's worth reading http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/206319/atsamd10-atmel-arm-programming-via-uart-bootloader in particular the idea of using the explained mini board is tempting, though one should try to verify if support for an off-board target has been achieved (potentially even by cutting traces to the on-board one).  If you end up back with an ST part like your development board rather than the Atmel, STM32 discovery and nucleo boards can SWD any STM32 subfamily as an external target, even if it doesn't match the on-board family.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you don't have the full datasheet, just the summary. It's available here under "Datasheet," not "Summary."

http://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/atmel/ATSAMD10C13A-SSUT/ATSAMD10C13A-SSUTTR-ND/5226466

This particular chip has Serial Wire Debug, or SWD. Search that datasheet for that. Two pins, one for clock and one for data. I would recommend purchasing a programmer.

http://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/atmel/ATATMEL-ICE/ATATMEL-ICE-ND/4753379

Good luck!

Comment: Thx you guys, It really clear mind :)